# UiButton as switch then have other buttons follow

Tags: ios, button, switch-statement

having trouble with this.
I have one UIButton i want to make as an on/off switch to tell other buttons to run a bit of code.
Basically, if the UIButton is "On" then all other buttons on the screen when tapped will change the view's background color randomly.
thanks for any help!

Here is the idea i am working with. Super new and not quite getting it. thanks for any help!!

```
// Buttons Play Sounds
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

- (IBAction)D1{
    [self playD1];

}

- (IBAction)A2{
    [self playA2];
}

- (IBAction)Bb3{
    [self playBb3];
}

- (IBAction)D5{
    [self playD5];
}

- (IBAction)G7{
    [self playG7];


// Make array of the buttons?
- (IBAction)switchNotes:(UIButton *)sender {


    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
    if(sender.selected)
    {
        NSLog(@"Switch is ON");
        for(UIButton *myButton in self.myButtonCollection) {
            // What to do?


        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Switch is OFF");
        for(UIButton *myButton in self.myButtonCollection) {
           // what to do? 
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Comment: What should the behavior be when the button is in off position?

Comment: Hi BeemerFan in the off position the view background color stays original black color. When On all buttons on the screen can change the background color

Answer (score 1):

You could implement in you random color generator an `if()` statement testing `youBut.selected` or another variable storing it like:

```
-(void)changeBackground:(UIButton*)sender{
if(!but.selected) return;
int r = rand() % 255;  // or implement special method to treat range with sender.tag
int g = rand() % 255;  
int b = rand() % 255;  
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:r Green:g Blue:b];

}
```

Comment: Thanks admin! so how would that tie into one of the sound buttons being tapped? thanks a ton!

Comment: @IanJames simply call this function in your IBActions like so: `[self changeBackground:sender]`. Note that you could either delete the argument in `changeBackground:` or implement tag in your buttons and modify your `play...` method so you know the sender and can pass it to the `changeBackground:` method